# Flutter ModalBottomSheet visibility

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I want to call a function after modal bottom sheet built. But i could not check bottom sheet build.  How can i check modal bottom sheet visibility and it is build?

Answer (score 1):

```
showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => Container())
        .then((value) => print('i am visible now!'));
```